# Is there a way to render markdown from declaration in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

In essence, I'm looking to be able to render content from a component's declaration in the actual component itself.

*Another component:*

```
<Page>
    <h1>A title</h1>
    <p>An amazing paragraph</p>
</Page>
```

*Page component:*

```
<template>
    <Header/>
    <!-- Here is where I want to render the title & paragraph-->
    <Footer/>
</template>
```

Vue does a similar function with the router's view, by exposing `<router-view/>` in the app's entry point. That's essentially what I would like to do except throughout components.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add `<slot/>` there:

```
<template>
    <Header/>
    <slot></slot>
    <Footer/>
</template>
```

Check out: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html